# lack of the file (cholrl.a) during make

Tags: makefile, lapack

I install Lapack-3.6.1 on Ubutun.There is a problem during make, lack of the file (cholrl.a). The error message is this.

> make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/lapack-3.6.1/BLAS/SRC' ( cd
>   SRC/VARIANTS ; make) make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/usr/local/src/lapack-3.6.1/SRC/VARIANTS' gfortran  -O2 -frecursive
>   -c cholesky/RL/cpotrf.f -o cholesky/RL/cpotrf.o gfortran  -O2 -frecursive -c cholesky/RL/dpotrf.f -o cholesky/RL/dpotrf.o gfortran  -O2 -frecursive -c cholesky/RL/spotrf.f -o cholesky/RL/spotrf.o gfortran  -O2 -frecursive -c cholesky/RL/zpotrf.f -o
>   cholesky/RL/zpotrf.o ar cr LIB/cholrl.a cholesky/RL/cpotrf.o
>   cholesky/RL/dpotrf.o cholesky/RL/spotrf.o cholesky/RL/zpotrf.o ar:
>   LIB/cholrl.a: No such file or directory Makefile:38: recipe for target
>   'cholrl' failed make[1]: *** [cholrl] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving
>   directory '/usr/local/src/lapack-3.6.1/SRC/VARIANTS' Makefile:39:
>   recipe for target 'variants' failed make: *** [variants] Error 2

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Have you searched for the file?  Is it contained in the Makefile? LIB looks like an unresoved variable, have you provided the dependencies?  gcc version?  dependency versions?

Answer (score 2):

Creating `LIB` directory myself worked for me. So, type `mkdir LIB` in `SRC/VARIANTS`.